# angular-ui ui-select2 - how to use query function

Tags: angular-ui, ui-select2

[ivaynberg's select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) has this great feature `query` ( a property of the `options` object that gets passed to the call to `select2({})`)

The trouble I'm having is using this feature with [angular-ui's ui-select2](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select2) implementation.

I wanna do something like:

```
$scope.select2Options = {
  query: function(options) {
    $http({
      method: 'GET'
      url: '/some/url'
      params: options.term
    })

    .success( function(result, status, headers, config) {
      // do some parsing here to get results looking right
      options.callback({result: result});
    });
}
```

like..I've not been able to get something like this working - query never gets called - and when I do as suggested on ivaynberg's github page and change the `<select>` to an `<input type="hidden" ... />` I see nothing.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug of ui-select2 which I made a pull request to address it but it's still pending. You could refer it here: [Ajax multiple bug fix for ui-select2](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select2/pull/187/files)

The fix is quite simple, you just need to add those lines inside the condition `angular.isString(viewValue)` in `controller.$render`

```
if (opts.ajax) {
  return;
}
```

Comment: I'll give this a try and report back with results - but to be clear - does this enable ajax only? or after this change, would query also work?

Comment: @KevinFriedheim I haven't tried with `query` option yet, but I think you could change the fix to `opts.ajax || opts.query`. Regards.